# How to set multiple values to list value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to select 2 options into droplist that were given by the user variables. The code below can select just one variable, so what I can do to select more than one. These variables are already on my list.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(()=>{
       var  value1 ="<?php echo $name1; ?>";
       var  value2 ="<?php echo $name2; ?>";
         $('#select option[value="' + value1 +'"]').attr("selected", "selected");
         $('#select option[value="' + value2 + '"]').attr("selected", "selected");
       });     
 </script>
```

Comment: Unless it's a multi-select, you can only have one selected option.

Comment: the select droplist is multiple, I want to select the option based on the variables.

Comment: That should work: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/y1dh4ez2/1/

Comment: Are you sure the correct values are being echoed? Use `View Source` to see what's being assigned to `value1` and `value2`.

Comment: This code should work, I am guessing the `value1` and `value2` are incorrect or you are trying to select by `option`'s html instead of value.

Also, in jQuery you can directly pass an array in select `val()` https://jsfiddle.net/jashwant/a1dL8xmo/2/

Comment: thanks, as Barmar and Jashwant said, the problem in the variables. the code works great!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simply you could use the [val](https://api.jquery.com/val/) function in jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(()=>{
      var  value1 ="<?php echo $name1; ?>";
      var  value2 ="<?php echo $name2; ?>";
        $('#select').val([value1, value2]);
      });     
</script>
```

Comment: Please stop using **var**, use **const** or **let**. Also a short echo mode is available. `const value1 = '<?=$name?>';`.

Comment: @MarkusZeller The answer is targeted to solve a problem, Not a code review.

Comment: So I reviewed your answer and it is my pleasure to point that out. Btw, that one line could have been a comment.